# My transitor amplifier is deamplifying

Tags: transistors, amplifier, music

I have built the following circuit intended to be an amplifier.
[image: circuit]

When I hook the input up to my phone via a guitar cable and the output to a 4 ohm speaker it produces a lower volume than plugging the phone straight into the speakers. The voltages I measure over the resistors do not match up to the tutorial I followed. I have tried switching the transistor and capacitors to no avail. My battery measures at 8.8V.

Comment: Compare the impedance of your speaker to the output impedance of that circuit.

Comment: I don't have an oscilloscope is there still a way to do this?

Comment: you could try maths.

Comment: Is the point that they're orders of magnitude different or do you really want to know?

Comment: Trying to drive a 4 ohm speaker (and expect some volume) with this type of amplifier is similar to using the motor from a moped to power a heavy truck. It's not going to work. This kind of amplifier is simply unsuitable for driving low impedance speakers. So forget that. Use it to amplify signals at line level so before it goes into a power amplifier. If you want to build a "proper" audio amplifier, get an LM386 module.

Comment: @ShibbyShtank: I want you to do the check, so that you know things for the future and learn how to spot that mistake the next time. Just telling you won't give you that tool at hand.

Comment: You designed an amplifier, but you also need a power stage to drive your load, add an emitter-follower before C2 (which also looks to be reverse biased).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output impedance of a phone is <10 ohms (it easily drives 8 ohm earbuds), so you're increasing the output impedance with your "amplifier": At the beginning, you bias it using a voltage divider with impedance of around 2kOhms, then at the end of the circuit your amplifier is based on a 4.7kOhm resistor, so it has output impedance of 4.7kOhms.  If you're driving a 4 ohm speaker, you have far too high output impedance.

Comment: Could this be solved by using smaller values on the resistors?

Comment: Probably not.  I'd recommend an op-amp amplifier with a push-pull follower, ask me if you'd like me to show that in my answer.

Comment: I might be back when I get my hands on an op-amp. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ShibbyShtank: Before you try the op-amp you need to do some calculations to understand what voltages and currents your speaker will require. Then you need to choose an amplifier to suit by checking specifications and datasheets.